# How to fix (process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.) on Android (NDK r20)?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Android_ndk\android-ndk-r20\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\FossAsia_CodeHeat\phimpme-android\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\FossAsia_CodeHeat\phimpme-android\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=arm64-v8a NDK_ALL_ABIS=arm64-v8a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=D:/FossAsia_CodeHeat/phimpme-android/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\FossAsia_CodeHeat\phimpme-android\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
Android NDK: ERROR:D:\FossAsia_CodeHeat\phimpme-android\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk:opencv_dnn: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file    
Android NDK: Check that D:/FossAsia_CodeHeat/phimpme-android/app/src/main/jni/../staticlibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_dnn.a exists  or that its path is correct   

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
C:/Android_ndk/android-ndk-r20/build//../build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:45: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

above error occurred when running the project!

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you how to fix this:

> Android NDK: ERROR:D:\FossAsia_CodeHeat\phimpme- android\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk:opencv_dnn: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
>   Android NDK: Check that D:/FossAsia_CodeHeat/phimpme-android/app/src/main/jni/../staticlibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_dnn.a exists  or that its path is correct

Comment: I tried on the given path as NDK location, but it haven't recognized as valid NDK Location.

Comment: What? The NDK location isn't the problem. The source file you're pointing to doesn't exist.

Comment: yes you're correct. i fix the problem by manually downloading releevant libraries.